# How do I get Outlook to compose new emails from the default account and not ignore the actual default setting on a Mac (Office 365)?

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook

I run Office 365 on a Mac (Yosemite)
I have two accounts in Outlook.
I have set a default account. However, each time I compose a message, it overrides my default account and opts for whatever account is currently in view. I do not prefer that behavior.

I see how to do this on a PC:

[How do I get Outlook to actually default new emails to a specific account and not ignore the default setting?](https://superuser.com/questions/548021/how-do-i-get-outlook-to-actually-default-new-emails-to-a-specific-account-and-no)

I am stuck at how to get around this "feature."

Will someone please point out the workaround for the Mac? I suspect it is editing these files:

Library - Group Containers - Outlook - Outlook 15 Profiles

Thank you so much.