# Outlook 2016 always replies from the same account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, outlook.com, activesync

I'm having a very strange issue with Outlook that has me stumped. I searched but was unable to find any information online regarding this issue (just related issues that didn't help).

I use Outlook 2016. Up until last week, I was using it with 5 different POP email accounts, which worked fine. When I created a new message, it would automatically send the email from the account that I am currently accessing. Or if I replied to an email, it would automatically send from the account that email was sent to. This worked well and it's how I wanted it.

Last week, I ended up adding another email account: this one an Exchange ActiveSync account from Outlook.com. Since that account was added, whenever I REPLY to an email, it chooses this outlook.com account as the sending account. The strange thing is that when I create a NEW email, it still works as before. It chooses the account I am currently accessing as the sending account.

The default email account is set as one of the other POP accounts. Not the Exchange.

The Exchange data file is set as the default data file (this is required so the Exchange calendar is displayed in my task bar).

In settings, the option to always send from a default account is NOT selected, which is correct since I want to send based on the account I am viewing.

I did find this article on SuperUser, but unfortunately it describes the opposite issue I'm having: [How do I get Outlook to actually default new emails to a specific account and not ignore the default setting?](https://superuser.com/questions/548021/how-do-i-get-outlook-to-actually-default-new-emails-to-a-specific-account-and-no)

This one has me stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. And have found the solution.

If you've added new Exchange account, its new OST data file has became the default one. After that, because of some strange reasons, every e-mail reply is set to be send via this new Exchange account.

SO JUST GO TO SETTING > DATA FILES and set some of your PST data files (the one that was default before adding the Exchange account) as default back again. And that's it. After that it works as it should.

Comment: This works, but you will lose your "To-do Bar" and creating a new calendar item from the email view will send it to the PST file rather than your outlook.com calendar.